# Google Visualization Chart Not Showing First Column

Tags: google-visualization

I am having an issue with the Google Visualization API in that some of the data in the chart is not showing. The chart is fairly simple, it has 4 columns and two rows.

http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=ae0853b788af3292b5547a5b7f1224aed76abfff

```js
 function drawVisualization() {
      // Create and populate the data table.

      var data_table = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data_table.addColumn({"type": "date","label": "Date"});
      data_table.addColumn({"type": "number","label": "A"});
      data_table.addColumn({"type": "number","label": "B"});
      data_table.addColumn({"type": "number","label": "C"});

      data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 5, 26)}, {v: 1}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]);
      data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 5, 27)}, {v: 2}, {v: 1}, {v: 0.5}]);

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
      chart.draw(data_table, {
          legend: "bottom"
      });

  }
```

When generated, the chart shows nothing for the first row (2013-5-26), and shows only the values of 2 and 1 for the second row (omitting 0.5).

I suspect this could be similar to [Google Column Chart Missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648365/google-column-chart-missing-data)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Interestingly, setting the first column to data type 'string' and setting the values as new Date(...).toString() seems to fix the problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems Google have provided the solution somewhat...

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Discrete_vs_Continuous

> Help! My chart has gone wonky!
>
> My domain axis type is not string but I still want a discrete domain axis:
>
> and this makes you terribly upset, then you can do one of the
>   following:
>
> 1. Change the type of your first data table column to string.
> 2. Use a DataView as adapter to convert the type of your first data table
>      column to string:

So the solution to the above chart was to add:

```js
//Create a DataView from the data_table
var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data_table);

//Set the first column of the dataview to format as a string, and return the other columns [1, 2 and 3]
dataView.setColumns([{calc: function(data, row) { return data.getFormattedValue(row, 0); }, type:'string'}, 1, 2, 3]);
```

So the whole function became:

```js
function drawVisualization() {
var data_table = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data_table.addColumn({"type": "date","label": "Date"});
  data_table.addColumn({"type": "number","label": "A"});
  data_table.addColumn({"type": "number","label": "B"});
  data_table.addColumn({"type": "number","label": "C"});

  data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 5, 26)}, {v: 1}, {v: 0}, {v: 0}]);
  data_table.addRow([{v: new Date(2013, 5, 27)}, {v: 2}, {v: 1}, {v: 0.5}]);

  //Create a DataView from the data_table
  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data_table);

  //Set the first column of the dataview to format as a string, and return the other columns [1, 2 and 3]
  dataView.setColumns([{calc: function(data, row) { return data.getFormattedValue(row, 0); }, type:'string'}, 1, 2, 3]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  chart.draw(dataView, {
      legend: "bottom"
  });
}
```

Comment: Anyway to do that more dynamically than having to add `1, 2 ,3`? Determined I can pass an `int` just fine if I call it a string... Now just stuck on dates like the OP was.